# Hide specific folders for a sftp user? Within chroot

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, sftp, chroot-jail

when using vsftpd there is an option to hide files or directories that matches a certain pattern in the variable hide_files. Can something similar be achieved when using SFTP/SSH?

Want I want to do is to let people log in to a chrooted directory where only some specific folders are hidden. Once logged in the users can upload files, and download files in the available folders. Also another User can only read them.

I have done a chroot jail for Users, but this is not possible because some Users need to see all Folders in the Chroot Jail.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with the widespread OpenSSH SFTP server.

---

But other SFTP servers do allow it. For example the ProFTPD with its [`HideFiles` directive](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_core.html#HideFiles). Note that while ProFTPD is primarily an FTP server, [it does support SFTP](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html) too.

A related question: [Some files/directories are not listed by ProFTPD server](https://superuser.com/q/867647/213663)